# Add Dropdown in Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, fieldtype

I've created Select Dropdown fieldtype and populated it manually. How do I display the select in a channel form?

The EE documentation states: This creates a standard HTML  drop-down list.

However when I add the {fieldtype} to my channel form nothing appears.

How do I add the Dropdown to my channel form?

Comment: Can you confirm that the field type has a value stored in it via the CP?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation for displaying select lists in Channel Forms](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#other-channel-fields):

> If you’re creating a select list, you’ll need to pull in the options, using `{options:my_field_name}` but otherwise things look pretty similar:

```
<select name="my_field_name" id="my_field_name">
  {options:my_field_name}
    <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
  {/options:my_field_name}
</select>
```